# Sort rows in datagridview by the sum of rows values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` and cells have value `bool` values `true` or `false`. I Need to sort rows based on having count of true values. The row which has most true cells should be at top and the row with least true values at bottom.

Data is in an Access database and I load data using `TableAdapter`.

[image]

Comment: For example i have datagridview [link](http://imgur.com/8lwkE2z) and cells have value true or false. Need to sort that the row which has the most true values were above and sorted in descending order

Comment: datasource is a Access data table. Connect in Data - Add data source

Comment: datagridview read only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- You can load data sorted from database.
- You can sort data by adding a computed column to `DataTable`.
- You can sort data using linq.

**Using Computed Column of DataTable**

Add a new column to the table, and set [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) of the column. Then sort table using [`DefaultView.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) property of data table:

```
table.Columns.Add("Value4", typeof(int), 
          "Convert(ISNULL(Value1,false), 'System.Int32') + " +
          "Convert(ISNULL(Value2,false), 'System.Int32') + " +
          "Convert(ISNULL(Value3,false), 'System.Int32')" );

table.DefaultView.Sort = "Value4 DESC";
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

**Using Linq**

You can use [`OrderByDescending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx) to sort rows based on count of true values in a row this way:

```
var temp = table.Clone();
table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemArray.OfType<bool>().Count(b=>b==true))
     .ToList().ForEach(x =>
     {
         temp.Rows.Add(x.ItemArray);
     });
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = temp;
```

Comment: Option with a link is good, but I can not understand how I replace the "table".  i have only binding source, datagridview and tableadapter

Comment: Something like this: `var temp= this.dataSet1.SomeTable.Clone();` and at last `this.bindingSource1.DataSource= temp;`