# Sort columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767036/sort-rows-in-datagridview-by-the-sum-of-rows-values) topic, I asked how to sort the rows by the sum of the values in the row. The solution was this:

```
var temp = myDataBaseDataSet.table1.Clone();
myDataBaseDataSet.table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.ItemArray.OfType<bool>().Count(b => b == true))
     .ToList().ForEach(x =>
     {
         temp.Rows.Add(x.ItemArray);
     });
this.table1DataGridView.DataSource = temp;
```

Now there's a new maybe stupid question: how to sort the column like rows in example above? Simply, to change the order of the columns (but save columns values)

I tried to make an application for an example. First I do the sorting in rows as already wrote. Then I need to swap the columns by the sum of the values of the columns and they should be placed in order of descending ( like on screenshot )
[image: Example of what i need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get an ordered list of columns from `DataTable` based on count of checked items in columns. Then remove corresponding columns from grid and add them in order this way:

```
var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Where(x => x.DataType == typeof(bool))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Column = x,
                    Count = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                .Count(r => r.Field<bool>(x) == true)
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .Select(x => x.Column).ToList();

columns.ForEach(x =>
{
    var column = grid.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
                    .Where(c => c.DataPropertyName == x.ColumnName)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    if (column != null)
    {
        grid.Columns.Remove(column);
        grid.Columns.Add((DataGridViewColumn)column.Clone());
        column.Dispose();
    }
});
```